# How to get function's parameter value without parameter name in swift?

Tags: swift

```
func test(_: [Int]) {
  print("xxx")
}

test([1,2,3])
```

I saw this code is valid in swift, how can I get the value passed into `test`?

Comment: I don't think you can. Isn't that the whole point of `_`?

Comment: Found [a bit of documentation explicitly saying that you can't.](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Declarations.html#ID472)

Comment: I just curious whether this a way to it. like JavaScript, this is a arguments object can do this

Comment: You're deliberately making it impossible to retrieve the parameter and then asking why you can't retrieve the parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To explicitly answer your question:

> how can I get the value passed in test?

You can't, in the same way that after

```
let _ = someFunction()
```

you have no way to get at the return value of `someFunction`. That's really the whole point of `_` which basically means "I'm ignoring this intentionally".

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the parameter value inside the function, you have to specify the parameterName. Swift's function has this kind of structure :

```
func someFunction(argumentLabel parameterName: Int) {
    // In the function body, parameterName refers to the argument value
    // for that parameter.
}
```

where argumentLabel is used on the function caller, for example

```
func eat(byWhom person: String){}
```

would become

```
eat(byWhom: "Victor")
```

in the caller code.
On the other hand, you can get the "Victor" value from the parameterName :

```
func eat(byWhom person: String){
    print(person) // should print "Victor"
}
```

Comment: the _ on your example's function parameter means that you are not using your parameterName inside your function, in order to use it you have to give it a name as specified above.

Comment: got it, thanks. I just curious whether this a way to it. like js, this is a arguments object can do this

Answer (score 0):

create function like this

`func test(_ value: [Int]) { }`

and then you can call it like this.

`test([1,2])` without mentioning the parameter name.

Answer (score 0):

There's no chance to get functions parameter value w/o its name. That is why it is being used. But you can do this:

```
func test(_ value: [Int]) {
  print(value)
}


test([1,2,3])
```